# How does ohm's law works in practice

Tags: alternator

1 Does this means for example that alternator even with low rotor magnetic field strength and low output voltage on stator will  obey ohm law and give current proportional to resistance and voltage .

2  Example in alternator why have 120 v output and load resistance of  4 ohm is connected and why reduce rotor excitation current output voltage is also reduced now output voltage is  20v  and resistance is 4 ohms how is now current calculated

My question is absolutely clear does alternator obey ohm low  because of vering execution current tu rotor for a people whu know how to answer my question is extremely  clear.

Comment: Your question will be closed soon, because nobody will understand what you are asking for

Comment: Ohm's law describes the relation between Voltage (V), Current (I) and resistance (R) in a closed electrical circuit. So rotors, stators, magnetic fields, exitations, the phase of the moon and Nicaragua's annual budget are **irrelevant** to Ohm's law. So you mentioning *low rotor magnetic field strength* is irrelevant, relevant is: what is the voltage ? What is the resistance ? What is the current ? Answer 2 of these 3 questions, Ohm's law allows you to determine the 3rd.

Comment: Ohms law is the relationship between current and voltage for a resistive load. Not all loads are resistive so it does not apply to all circuits.

Comment: I must admit  that it's difficult to understand what this all is about (=inferior english and worryless mix of non-related terms). I quess that you try to understand how Ohm's law should be applied to calculate how much an alternator gives current and how much the voltage drops when loaded. Unfortunately alternators are much more complex than a resistor. Ohm's law is not enough. Also the datasheet with numerical specification and characteristic curves of the alternator is a must.

Comment: 120 / 4    30 a   20  /4    5 a

Comment: @user161541: "*My question is absolutely clear ...*". No it is not. Several users with high reputation - and that means they understand this subject - have said that it is not clear. There is a schematic diagram tool on the editor toolbar. Draw a schematic of the alternator including internal resistance and inductance and load. Then show your equations. Someone may be able to help you then.

Answer (score 5):

> How does ohm's law works in practice?

The same as it works in theory. \$ V = IR \$.

1. Yes, provided that the current doesn't exceed the maximum current of the alternator. You have given a bad example because alternators have built-in regulators to adjust the field strength to keep output voltage constant.
2. I don't understand what you are asking but if output voltage is 20 V and resistance is 4 Ω then current will be given by \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {20}{4} = 5 \; A \$.

> i (sic) am asking how to calculate current output of alternator for different output voltages.

The maximum current at low voltages will usually be the same rated current at maximum voltage. This is due to the gauge of wire used in the windings.

Comment: The maximum current at low voltages will usually be the same rated current at maximum voltage. This is due to the gauge of wire used in the windings

Comment: ok  but this means the alternator do not obey ohm law

Comment: Show me your calculations.

Comment: The **rated** current is **not** related to Ohm's law ! A **Rated** current means: it is OK to use at this current. Ohm's law does not care about ratings. If voltage and resistance are such that 100 A will flow but the rating is only 10 A then there's a problem. Then the voltage must be lowered and/or the resistance increased so that the current is equal or less than 10 A. Ohm's law only concerns itself with the current that would flow, it does not care if anything blows up or melts as a result of that. The alternator does not behave like a resistor so how can it obey Ohm's law ?

Comment: 120 / 4    30 a     20  /4    5 a

Comment: I am asking this because of alternator output current calculation you  know the alternator output voltage is proportional tu rotor excitation current as why reduce excitation tu rotor output voltage will drop and load resistance is constant haw in this situation calculate output current what formula i use

Comment: Please use capital letters, punctuation (. , ?) and equals signs in your formulas. Check your spelling before posting. It is very difficult to know what you are saying. Please edit your comments above.

Comment: I am asking this because of alternator output current calculation. You know the alternator output voltage is proportional tu rotor excitation current as why reduce excitation tu rotor output voltage will drop and load resistance is constant haw in this situation calculate output current what formula i use.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the most global definition of Ohm law : U = ZI, with Z = R + jX, Z being the complex impedance, R being your resistance and X your reactance (see capacitors and coils for common applications of this version).

This is that simple, yet it can lead to giant numbers of layers understanding (a capacitor also act as a coil in very high frequencies, who would guess !).

Now about your alternator. An alternator, in normal use, is pretty much an inverted motor : a generator, a coil and a output resistor. If your output resistor is too high (let's say 8 ohm), then you'll get a voltage drop on your 4ohm load because if will be Ul = Ug * RL/(RL+RS), Ul being the voltage in your load, ug the non reduced (no load) voltage of your alternator and RS the output resistor equivalent of the coil inside your alternator.