# How do I calculate the output current of an alternator

Tags: alternator

Do alternators obey Ohm’s law? The alternator output voltage is proportional to the rotor excitation current. When reducing rotor excitation, the output voltage drops and the load resistance stays constant. Can why still use ohm law to determine the output current.

Example alternator 480 v / 4 ohm current output is 120 a if why now reduce rotor excitation output voltage drops tu 220 v / 4 ohm output current is 55 a can why calculete like this.

Another example is car alternator have 900 w of pawer tu give that pawer with 13.7 v output current is 65 a and load resistance is 0.21077 this all calculation are based on ohm low.

Can why calculate like this of course every equipment must support rated current

also i understand principle of impedance can why calculate a show i above examples

if why can apply ohm's law tu alternator haw why can determinant output current

i am really confused about this because i am always thought that resistance determine the current same people say they alternator does not follow ohm law ok but haw then calculate current output and load itself

Comment: This is basically the same question as this one: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/326968/how-does-ohms-law-works-in-practice?rq=1

Comment: You just copied [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/326793/how-do-i-calculate-the-output-current-of-an-alternator) here, together with all spelling mistakes and without attribution. This is a violation of terms of service.

Answer (score 1):

> Do alternators obey Ohm’s law?

Under all circumstances output current is output voltage / resistance.

If someone says that this isn't true then maybe they are thinking of a more complex situation but this isn't clear what that might be from your question.

Comment: and resistance includes not only the load but the internal resistance as well...

Comment: @SolarMike that might be confusing to the OP. If the OP just regards the output voltage as the terminal voltage across the output load then internal resistance is accommodated by the fact that the output voltage falls due to load current.

Comment: won't mention that alternators on cars are 3-phase then :) either star or delta...